# Passing numeric arguments to Makefile.am in Autoconf

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, variable-declaration

I'm trying to pass the version information from configure.ac to Makefile.am using three numeric variables, which is used to set the -version-info parameter during compilation of the .so file.

This is my **configure.ac**:-

```
current=4
revision=2
age=1
AC_INIT([rdma2], [3.1], [myname@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CXX(g++)
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([config])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([version: $current.$revision.$age])
SET_MISC($current,"$revision","$age")
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile])
```

The value for current, revision and age is NOT being passed to Makefile.am! They are all blank variables despite me defining them very clearly in the beginning of the file. Am I not using variable definition correctly here?

The message that is printed for:-

```
AC_MSG_NOTICE([version: $current.$revision.$age])
```

is

```
...
configure: version: ..
...
```

Why won't it take my input value?

Comment: Assignment to variables works only after AC_INIT. Before it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, because the parsing starts at AC_INIT and everything before that, is not used by autoconf. You can try, something like this:

```
AC_INIT([rdma2], [3.1], [myname@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([config])
AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT
AC_SUBST([current], [4])
AC_SUBST([rev], [2])
AC_SUBST([build], [1])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([version: $current.$rev.$build])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

AC_SUBST make variables visible on child makefiles.am. But if you really want to be before AC_INIT the variables declaration, try [m4](http://mbreen.com/m4.html) macros.

```
# m4 macro
define(MESSAGE, Current version status)
# say hello to autoconf
AC_INIT([rdma2], [3.1], [myname@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([config])
AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT
AC_SUBST([current], [4])
AC_SUBST([rev], [2])
AC_SUBST([build], [1])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([MESSAGE: $current.$rev.$build])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Great! The *define* macro was what I was looking for! Thanks!